# Keep all jars in a folder running on jvm's as services

Tags: linux, java, service

On a remote server I'm having a folder which contains serveral jars. Each of it will represent an application, which will open up a port, on which a web-application is served.

It might look like this:

```
jars
   app1.jar
   app2.jar
   app3.jar
```

I'm trying to find a solution now to ensure that all of them are constantly running on separated jvm's. Whenever one jar is replaced by another uploaded jar, this should immediately be handled.

At the moment I can achieve parts of this manually by setting up a service for each of it. Something like:

```
my-servers-service-setup-tool app1 java -jar app1.jar 12345
```

(last parameter is the port)

In case app1.jar is now overridden by an upload: How could the service react on that? Either restart itself or if this is necessary setup a new service for the same port.

If a new jar enters the folder, I'd setup a new service for this as described above. Might there maybe be a more declarative approach to this? I mean, another automation that would detect the arrival of a new jar and that would setup a new service.

Comment: Isn't this what cronjobs are for?

Comment: I would not know how cronjobs might help here. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Depends on how you want to set it up I guess. You can use a shell script to poll that directory, looking for new jar's and have it setup new services as appropriate if it finds one without a corresponding service and if it finds a jar newer than the corresponding service's `ps -p $PID -o etime` value then it can restart the web service to pick it up. I suppose you could also do this in puppet, giving the users deploying the app rights to the `files` directory on the module that manages this service. Puppet can then trigger a refresh of the service on changes.